# Maven build failing after adding classpath and dependencies in lib folder in pom.xml NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, maven, class, build

I have an app I built in Java and successfully compiled in Maven. After building I go to the target folder and run `java -jar *projectfilename*.jar` and I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jibble/pircbot/PircBot
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at io.github.bholagabbar.Main.setupIRCBot(Main.java:9)
    at io.github.bholagabbar.Main.main(Main.java:27) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jibble.pircbot.PircBot
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Now `org/jibble/pircbot/PircBot` which was not found is actually one of my dependencies in my pom.xml.

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>io.github.pixrat</groupId>
  <artifactId>gallurdo</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>gallurdo</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>
                ${project.build.directory}/lib
              </outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
              <mainClass>io.github.pixrat.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>jitpack.io</id>
      <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>pircbot</groupId>
      <artifactId>pircbot</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.Ullink</groupId>
      <artifactId>simple-slack-api</artifactId>
      <version>0.5.1</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have referred to answer here [Maven: NoClassDefFoundError in the main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797860/maven-noclassdeffounderror-in-the-main-thread), [Maven: NoClassDefFoundError in the main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797860/maven-noclassdeffounderror-in-the-main-thread) and many other places but in vain. I'd appreciate some help thanks

Comment: This is probably what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729054/including-dependencies-in-a-jar-with-maven

Comment: I tried that dude. Same errpr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the JavaDoc for the `NoClassDefFoundException`:

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a `ClassLoader` instance
>    tries to load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call
>    or as part of creating a new instance using the `new` expression)
>    and no definition of the class could be found.
>
> The searched-for class definition existed when the currently
>     executing class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be
>     found.

and the scope `provided` means that the JDK or the container provide the dependency. As you are trying to execute your program as standalone on Java SE and if your library is not part of JDK your dependency will not be available at runtime, and hence throwing this exception.

So either remove the `<scope>provided</scope>` so that the default applies or change it to `compile` instead.

Comment: remove <scope>provided</scope> and replace with compile did it! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the maven shade plugin. For Eg.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <createDendencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>      // this is optional
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

What this will do is, it will create one single jar which would contain your compiled java code as well as the contents of all the jar dependencies that you mention in you pom. 
This is almost like you extracting all the jars in some location and creating one single jar out of this location.

Comment: Yes, if your application has a main class. But before that, why don't you give it a try just with the plugin.

Comment: were you able to create a consolidated jar after adding this plugin ?

Comment: I was. I get 2 jars called 'original-projectnamejar' and the other as 'projectnamejar'