# Program runs fine in Eclipse, but throws error when Jar is run on the command line

Tags: java, maven

Compiled with `mvn package` , I then try to run the `jar` with java `-jar app.jar` and it runs, but then throws a

> NoClassDefFoundError

The program runs completely fine in Eclipse.

How do I stop this from happening so I can run the program in the command line?

Comment: looks like some missing dependencies in you jar

Comment: when you say it runs fine in eclipse, you mean as a maven project yes?

Comment: @eddyce Yes - Imported maven project, runs fine in eclipse but then once compiled with mvn package and I try to run in comman line throws error - Very new to maven

Comment: Another one.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797860/maven-noclassdeffounderror-in-the-main-thread

Comment: ...yes check those questions, anyway you should use the shade plugin with maven http://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are missing dependencies. Try putting this in your pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>yourpackage.YourClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And then run:
java -jar [your-package-jar-with-dependencies.jar]

Comment: Hi - I now have the error - no main manifest attribute. I replaced the <mainClass></mainClass> with my package and class name

Comment: try running: java -cp your-jar-with-dependencies.jar yourpackage.YourClass

Comment: I now get the same error as previous NoCLassDefFoundError

Comment: Maybe if you share your pom.xml file, it will help us figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to guess, but when you paste your pom.xml here, I am pretty sure we'll see that you have some dependency. If you do so, this dependency must be included in the classpath when running java directly.